# How to discover Rest services

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I am using Rest service and i have been searching for how Rest services discovery is done but i didn't find any tutorial on that, all i have found is that a Rest service can be described using WADL or WSDL version 2.0. what i want to understand is how are these descriptions used? as an example if i had this WADL description:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 2.5-SNAPSHOT 2013-12-20 17:14:21"/>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:9998/">
        <resource path="country/{id}">
            <param xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="xs:int" style="template" name="countryId"/>
            <method name="GET" id="getCountry">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="application/xml"/>
                </response>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

how can the client consuming the service access that? can anyone help me?

Comment: The descriptions are used to generate type safe clients or stubs as well as a documentation source by using XSLT (or other technologies). CXF I believe will generate clients based on WADL in a similar manner to WSDL.

Comment: does that mean descriptions are not used for discovery?

Comment: Pretty much yes. You could use WADL for discovery (of endpoint addresses) much the same WSDL is abused for that as well but it is not real discovery. What is used for discovery of REST services it not really defined but in theory you can use WSDD (which is the WSDL/SOAP method of discovery). Many people use a some sort of distributed configuration store like etcd,consul,zookeeper,eureka etc.